# Shortcode echo [shortcode] instead of function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm using wordpress with Woocommerce and am trying to call the

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_pay]'); ?>`

shortcode from within a php page.
Problem is that it gives us this result: `[woocommerce_pay]` instead of actually "performing" the shortcode and showing us the payment form.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Does your theme support shortcodes? If not, you need to turn them on in the functions.php file.

Comment: @ScottSimpson I've confirmed that shortcodes do indeed work.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure the shortcode is placed in the "Text" tab of the page editor instead of the "Visual" tab.

If you're calling it through PHP: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]'); ?>`. If you're doing it this way, you can't do this within the "Text" tab of the page unless you've allowed PHP to run from within a page. You need to add the PHP to a template file.

Here is a reference: [Wordpress Codex for Shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Comment: My bad, I'm calling it through PHP.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't show the [woocommerce_pay] anymore, but also doesn't show the form.

Comment: Stupid question: Is the plugin activated?

Comment: Yes. It's in the dashboard and I have other parts of it working.

Comment: Updated my answer again to cover other issues.